# How to Filter Data from Repeater control in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filtering, repeater, datarow

How to Filter Data from Repeater control in C#?

**Repeater control :**

All (15)

---

shoes (3)

---

shirts (12)

---

And On Click click i want to filter data/row (posts)  from Repeater control.

if i click on shoes 3 posts should display only but by default all 15 posts should display.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" 
     NavigateUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.id", "./Default.aspx?id={0}")%>'>
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Category")%>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

please suggest me  thanks in advance.

Comment: You should filter the datasource before binding it to Repeater. Post your code where you  are binding the source to Repeater.

Comment: protected void BindRepeaterData()
        {

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, category, ( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM entry_table WHERE category.id = entry_table.cat_id) as cnt FROM category", con);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            RepDetails.DataSource = ds;

            RepDetails.DataBind();


            con.Close();


        }

Comment: <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.id", "./Default.aspx?id={0}")%>'>
 <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Category")%>

</asp:HyperLink>

Comment: if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindRepeaterData();
            }

Comment: What I can understand from your code is, you want to populate a the records when the link is clicked. It is not filtering. You have to add another control (I would prefer GridView) in Default.aspx. In that page's Page_Load method you have to get querystring value of id. Then you have to run a sql query to get data from entry_table. This query result should be GridView's DataSource. You can see lots of works you have to do. I would suggest to search here for each steps, look at the examples.

Comment: u r right...i want to populate the records in default page.